# How 3005: disable to convert [0.5] to long do you have to solve?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[image]

If I put CSV file into Elasticsearch using kibana, there will be an error. I don't think it's a problem with mapping, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

check CSV file. obviously 50 lines have problem and does not match with grok pattern.